# Converting a string to an xs:dateTime

Tags: datetime, xquery

How do I convert Strings of the form "Sun Feb 25 19:31:07 +0000 2018" to `xs:dateTime` in XQuery? Maybe first converting the String into an ISO 8601 datetime format?

Answer (score 3):

With that format you got lucky as `parse-ietf-date("Sun Feb 25 19:31:07 +0000 2018")` should do: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yh/1.

According to https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ the `parse-ietf-date` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-ietf-date function is new in XQuery 3.1, so check whether your XQuery engine supports it. If not, you can perhaps use an extension module or function of the particular processor or engine you use or call into Java or another platform/language for the parsing.